# How to use Arguments in Custom Functions using Officejs

Tags: excel, office-js, custom-functions-excel

WE developed Excel add-in in OfficeJS with Custom Functions. Also it is deployed into domain server and below are the findings.

1) In online Excel Custom Functions with minimum of single arument able to invoke Web api and binding the data into Excel.
2) But for Desktop Excel same is working with minimum of two arguments and able to Api data to Excel cells and it is not working for minimum of single argument scenario.

Can you please confirm about Desktop scenario why it is not working with minimum of single argument.

Comment: Any error you may notice for minimum of single argument scenario for Desktop? It might also be helpful for debugging to share some code snippet.

Comment: @xiaochun ...I checked regedit file also but could not get the exact error. Can you please confirm below piece of used to create Custom functions...     
% inplace of @ symbol  

SAMPLE                                                                                                                                 
/**
 * Calculates the value
 * %CustomFunction Calctst1 Calctst1 
 * %param id[][]
 * %param [endDate] eDate CustomDate
 * %param [currency] 
*/

Comment: What's the result is in Excel cells when you execute the custom function? Is it "#NAME" or "#VALUE" or something else? I am not sure if Custom functions can be created well with the piece of codes you shared. Please check the function meta data file to see if the function is created as expected.